# Stream web page from server to youtube live

Tags: youtube, server, stream, html, live

I'm trying to find a package for Linux servers or an online service to stream a webpage with live content directly to Youtube Live.

It's pretty much like a screen cast made from your computer to Youtube Live (with a software) but from an online service or directly using your server.

Do you know any services or techniques to do that ?

Thanks